# If every point of the three dimensional space is coloured red, green or blue prove that one colour attains all distances

Tags: contest-math

The problem as stated in the title is taken from "Putnam and beyond". Below is the problem as stated in the book:

> Every point of the three-dimensional space is coloured red, green, or blue.
>   Prove that one of the colours attains all distances, meaning that any positive real number represents the distance between two points of this colour.

In the following I present my "solution" to the problem. It differs from the textbook solution, so I am unsure if it is correct or not. I would be grateful if any of you could confirm that it is correct or else show me where my argument breaks down.

Assume the contrary is true. Let $r,g$ and $b$ be the number of red, green and blue points respectively and let $r \geq g \geq b$ without loss of generality. By assumption some distance $d$ exists, which no two red points are apart. Now consider all spheres with red points at their centre and of radius $d$.  As the centre red point of each sphere is a distance $d$ from all points on the spheres surface, no points on the surface can be red and hence must be blue or green. This implies that the number of green points $g$ or the number of blue points $b$ must be greater than the number of red points $r$. But this contradicts our assumption $r \geq g \geq b$ and therefore we conclude that no such distance $d$ can exist. My argument is concluded.

The only issue that I would see with my above reasoning is that the quantities ( at least two of them, without the problem becoming trivial) $r,g$ and $b$ are infinite, so I may run into countability arguments.

Thank you for any help!

(note: I am aware of the textbook solution. Here I am interested in seeing whether my own solution makes any sense)

Comment: Suppose there are uncountably many red, green, and blue points.  Then your argument doesn't work.

Comment: A sort of "Ramsey theory"?

Comment: @ saulspatz Ah, OK this does ruin my argument. Thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz  Just once concern: Suppose r,g and b are uncountable and again construct the spheres. For each red point then we have again uncountably many green or blue points. I am far from an expert on countability, but surely there must be more green/blue points than red points...?!

Comment: No, that isn't so.  Infinite cardinals don't work like finite cardinals.  Besides, every point in $3-$space is the center of infinitely many spheres, and also lies on the surface of infinitely many spheres.  You don''t conclude that there are more points in $3-$space than there are in $3-$space, surely?

Comment: @saulspatz OK I understand and I see where I went wrong. Thank you !